# Network Manager not working [Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

Checking via systemctl status NetworkManager:
[Image of  problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zl8G.png)

When trying to do sudo service network-manager restart, it comes with this result:

> job for networkmanager.service failed because the control process exited with error code<

Due to this it will not connect, wired or not. It was working right last night and I have no idea why it's acting up now. I'm not an expert or experienced to be able to know what is probably obvious. So please help me out here, I want to continue using this laptop for school and future projects.
 I have tried to do restart and start, however it comes with the same error.

I will have to do a wipe if it cannot be resolved by tonight due to needing a useable school computer.

Laptop model: HP 15-da0012dx

Comment: I'd try to get a bit more info from log (journal). It seems NetworkManager crashed from whatever reason (see the log) and then tries to restart too quickly and that's the final reason why it failed. But you need to get to the bottom of this.
Another question could be if you have done any change to the configuration of the NetworkManager?

Comment: @puzzle last i recall i was trying to change the wifi.scan-rand-mac-address to equal no. Due to me trying to use the pau05 wifi adapter, which turned out to just have crapped out. I am checking the logs and its saying it is failing to read that exact configuration which means its probably pointing to me about how i changed that. Although if i do have to change that back, the problem begins of not knowing how as im not that advanced in ubuntu yet. Still an early intermediate. I do apologize if what i said wasnt concise, im on phone atm.

Comment: So it might be related to the last change after all. Try to check the new configuration then, it might be in a wrong format, so NetworkManager can't read such a file.

Comment: @puzzle Network manager is now working again, thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Not at all, you managed to repait it all yourself.